# How to add files into features in SharePoint solution

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Actually in my project there are two `.aspx` files. I want to add them into two different features called `feature1` and `feature2`. This is my project.

[image]

Is there any way to do this ? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Module** for that ! With module you can add files to your WSP solution (and deploy this files to document Library)
And after, don't forget to add your module in your feature

[How to: Include Files by Using a Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231524(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: You mean only modules can  be added to features ? can't we delete the files inside the module after adding to the feature ?

Comment: You can't add files (aspx) directly to your feature, you need module to tell where you want to deploy your files in your SharePoint site (in a liste, in the rootFolder ...) when the feature is activated.

Comment: The module is juste a **container**, so if you delete aspx files from your Visual Studio Solution, your module will deploy nothing ;)

Comment: ThanQ for your time